# shutdown redis-server from command line

Tags: macos, command-line, redis

I am trying to shutdown my redis-server from a redis-cli. Whenever I issue a command from a client I receive the error "(error) NOAUTH Authentication required." I have tried the commands "SHUTDOWN" and "SHUTDOWN NOSAVE".

I have also tried "redis-server stop" from another terminal window but received the error "# Fatal error, can't open config file 'stop'"

How can I shut down this server?
(I am on OSX).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Redis server is configured with a password apparently. Therefore, when using redis-cli, you'll need to issue the `AUTH password` command before any other command or else you'll be getting that error message (replace `password` with your server's password).

Alternatively, you can invoke `redis-cli` with the `-a` switch followed by your password for the same result.

To find the password of your server, open the Redis configuration file (by default `/etc/redis/6379.conf`) and look for the line starting with `requirepass` - whatever value is next to it, is the password.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ended up killing the redis-server process from the activity manager. I am going recreate the behavior I was seeing earlier and try out your more civilized way of handling to problem.

Comment: my /etc/redis/6379.conf is empty so how do I find the password now?

Comment: You'll need to find which conf file your server uses - by default, Redis is not protected by a password.

Answer (score 9):

```
1. redis-cli
2. auth yourpassword
3. shutdown
4. sudo service redis_6379 start
```

Comment: Can you expand on why this is the correct answer and what it does to solve OP's issue.

Comment: I got ERR Errors trying to SHUTDOWN. Check logs after typing shutdown

Answer (score 7):

You have to manually edit the start/stop-service script:

```
sudo vi /etc/init.d/redis_6379
```

Find the following line:

```
$CLIEXEC -p $REDISPORT shutdown
```

And replace it with the following 'changeit' is where your password goes:

```
$CLIEXEC -p $REDISPORT -a changeit shutdown
```

Now you should be able to start and stop the service without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

On Amazon EC2 instance I could restart local Redis like this:

`sudo /etc/init.d/redis restart`

P.S. If you are using Redis Authentication you have to pass `-a <pass>` parameter.