# How to start and stop redis service with authentication?

Tags: redis

I've set a password for my Redis server and when I try to restart the Redis server with sudo service redis_6379 restart then I get the following error message:

NOAUTH Authentication required.

How can I pass my password through the restart command?

The Redis version is 3.0.3.

Comment: Which Redis version?

Comment: Redis version: 3.0.3

Comment: Yep - this is a known issue :( my PR is waiting for merge: https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/2069

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could modify your `init.d/redis_6379` script and use the `-a` parameter of `redis-cli` to specify the password:

```
CLIEXEC="/usr/local/bin/redis-cli -a your_secret"
```

Comment: More precisely the solution was this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28658706/241739

You only need a password for stopping the server, not for starting.

Answer (score 4):

redis-cli connect to your server and authenticate yourself.

1. $ redis-cli -a *serverpassword*
2. $ shutdown
3. $ quit