# Redis raises "NOAUTH Authentication required" error but there is no password setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq

I got error **NOAUTH Authentication required** when I connect to Redis server via command: `redis-cli` and run `ping` to check if Redis is working.

I found [answer for NOAUTH Authentication required error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396336/shutdown-redis-server-from-command-line%20and) which describes that this error only happens when Redis is set a password, but I checked Redis config file at `etc/redis/redis.conf` and there is no password setting.

[image: Redis config]

Does anyone know that if there are other settings which can cause this error? Thanks for any help.

p/s: I am using Ruby on Rails web framework, Redis database is used for Sidekiq.

Edited: Redis version is 2.8.4. Server is hosted on AWS.

Currently, I decided to set a password for Redis server so that it can not be set password when it is running.

(When Redis server is restarted, it will work normal. You can run `sudo service redis-server restart` to restart Redis server.)

Comment: It could be that this isn't the config file that your server is using. Alternatively, it may be that someone connected to your server and set a password using the `CONFIG SET requirepass` command, in which case a restart of you Redis server should sort that out.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I sure that it is config file my server is using.  Yes, I restart Redis server and it works again without password, but I don't know why it requires password later, and I can not run `CONFIG get requirepass` to get the password.

Comment: Probably because someone is connecting to your server and setting requirepass.

Comment: I am sure that no one change this. But does it effect without setting in config file, just change via command line and it is applied?

Comment: Yep - all config directives (I think) can be changed during runtime. Sending a [`CONFIG REWRITE`](http://redis.io/commands/config-rewrite) persists the changes in the conf file.

Comment: Even we are getting the same issue. Were you able to figure out the specific reason for it?

Comment: @Puneeth we have not figured out the root cause of this problem

Comment: @Puneeth I decided to set password for Redis server to check if it still get this error.

Comment: @KienThanh thanks for getting back!   Can you please provide details about the redis version you are using?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

We also faced a similar issue. Looks like someone scanned AWS, connected to all public redis servers, and possibly ran "CONFIG SET REQUIREPASS ''", thus locking down the running instance of redis. Once you **restart** redis, the config is restored to normal.

Best thing would be to use AWS security group policy and **block port 6379** for public.

Comment: In my case, the troll cleared the database (ran FLUSHALL), then ran CONFIG SET REQUIREPASS '', twice.

Luckily I had backups, thank you for pointing the exact vunerability that allowed him to do this, and how to fix it.

Comment: Seems like the very reasonable explanation, had same problem on AWS

Comment: I think I have the same problem, but how did you restart redis? When I try "sudo /etc/init.d/redis_6379 restart", I get
"Stopping ...
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required."

Comment: Nevermind, I found the PID and sudo kill'd the process.

Comment: @Kohanz you can run `sudo service redis-server restart` to restart redis

Comment: @KienThanh thanks but that didn't work for me (perhaps it was not installed as a service?)

Answer (score 14):

I'm running Redis with Docker and there is an authentication password with the `REDIS_PASSWORD` env variable.

After connecting to the container with `docker exec` command, connect to redis CLI by entering the `redis-cli` command.

Then enter `auth {password}`, (the password that is set with the `REDIS_PASSWORD`)

Answer (score 11):

specific your redis password in the `redis-cli` command line
eg:

```bash
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a "$your_password"
```

check your `$your_password`.

It's recommend to add double quote to the password on the command line.

Comment: I think `-a` should be used for the password. This worked for me `sudo -u redis -g redis redis-cli --user admin -h ${IP_ADDRESS} -p 6379 -a "$ADMIN_PASS"`

Comment: @vikramaditya234 You are right. I‘ve corrected my typo.

Answer (score 5):

Redis password has been saved in `redis.conf` in this `/etc/redis/` directory
you are able to see/edit redis config/password by:

```
sudo vim /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Scroll to the `SECURITY` section and look for a commented directive that reads(use `/` to enter a phrase to search in vim and press enter):

```
# requirepass foobared
```

Uncomment it by removing the `#`, and change the foobared to a secure password (save changes by press `esc` key and `:wq`).

you can use `openssl` to generate a secure password to use in real project on server:

```
openssl rand 60 | openssl base64 -A
```

and copy secure password to `redis.conf`
or use a simple password for learning on the local machine.
After the password is changed don't forget to restart the redis service by:

```
sudo systemctl restart redis.service
```

use `redis-cli` to enter redis shell.
then enter password using `auth`.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> auth your_password
OK
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

credits goes to DigitalOcean Community read more about securing redis [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-redis-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04).

Answer (score 4):

I Have the same problem. after that I'm set `requirepass` for the `redis` server. 
 
And add that password in `initializer/redis.rb`

```
$redis = Redis.new(:password=>"****")
```

It works fine

Comment: you should also limit connect to your Redis port if your server is installed on AWS.

Answer (score 4):

Had the exact same problem running Redis on an AWS instance. I would restart redis-server without any password requirements (#requirepass ''), would work fine for a few hours, then would throw "NOAUTH Authentication required" and eventually would have to restart redis-server.

Checked the Security Groups settings in AWS for the instance and saw port 6379 open to the public (0.0.0.0/0). We limited the port access to our only server that needs to access and haven't seen the issue come up ever since!

P.S. This is my first ever contribution to StackOverflow. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue (running on AWS) and discovered our redis port was exposed. You probably had the same. Someone was messing around.

EDIT:
The solution: [reset your redis password](http://www.linuxsecrets.com/blog/15questions-troubleshooting/2015/10/08/1660-resetting-lost-redis-server-admin-password) and then (assuming you have it running as a service) restart the service [providing the new password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28658706/1731005)

Comment: Yes, I restarted server and it works normal but then stuck again. So I decided to set a password for it so that it can not set new password again.

Comment: Do you have your redis port (presumably 6379) exposed to the world? Closing it is the first step in the solution.

Comment: Yes, maybe the server is not protected port 6379 of redis. My solution is set a password for redis server so it can not be override password.

Answer (score 2):

If you have made any changes in configuration file then don't forget to restart redis service with `sudo service redis-server restart` command.

**Edit:**
If you are running redis service in production mode then redis requires password to run. For that you need to set password in your config file present at `/etc/redis`.

You need to set `requirepass *******` in that file under `########### SECURITY ############` section.

Then restart your server `sudo service redis-server restart`.

After that add that password in your config or initializer file where you have set your hostname and port.
Example:

`$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379, :password => "*******")`

Comment: I did not make any change, the Redis server require a password when it is running while configuration is not set password.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a try: `auth 'foobared'` It should be default password in config file: /etc/redis/redis.conf

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same problem, I found it's caused by someone starting redis with another `redis.cnf` configure file, So I stopped redis-server and then  started redis-server to specify a configure file.

```
redis-server /etc/redis.cnf
```

Then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on localhost so just tried this, which is default behaviour by the way:

```
redis-cli
auth admin
```

And it worked.
By the way if anyone just struggling for

> redis.conf

(as i was) just use:

```
nano /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

you can also see you password here in redis.conf file against

> requirepass (can search for it in file)

Note: Don't use such configuration for production its just for localhost.