# Setting requirepass on redis throws 'NOAUTH Authentication required'

Tags: django, nginx, redis, gunicorn, django-channels

I tried using the options setting to provide the password as such:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'OPTIONS': {
            "PASSWORD": 'pass',               },                                                                                                                                   'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('localhost', 6379)],                                                                                                  }
    }
}
```

Despite this, it is erroring:

```
Exception Value: NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

I found the following SO:

[Redis raise error: NOAUTH Authentication required but there is no password setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115213/redis-raise-error-noauth-authentication-required-but-there-is-no-password-setti)

But the answers were not helpful in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: If you have any special symbols in your password it will throw base 10 error. You're going to either have to convert the password to be url friendly or use a password without special characters.

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("redis://:mypassword@127.0.0.1:6379/0")],
        },
    },
}
```

Credits to PanosTrak from Discord and this [github issue](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/164)